# Question about Vacuum Rabi Splitting

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm studying cavity QED and I'm confused about Vacuum Rabi Splitting.

Mostly, Vacuum Rabi Splitting has been described when the two-level atom are in the excited state at the beginning with no photon in the cavity, and then it emits the photon with the atom in the ground state.

With interaction hamiltonians, I could see the normal mode splitting, but I wonder why it is called "vacuum" splitting.

I guess it's because there's no photon at the beginning in the cavity so that's why it is called "vacuum" splitting.

What if the atom is in the ground state at the beginning? I guess it is impossible to see normal mode splitting in the cavity without at least a single photon.

So, my question is why this procedure is called "vacuum" splitting even though there is a single photon in the cavity?

Please help me out.